# Access object property using variable numeric or string

Tags: javascript, object

The question is not only about the posiblity of the numerical object keys but also about the number variable is a numeric or string (Coercion)? as JSelser stated.

I wonder how this is posible:

```
var name = {1:"Bob",2:"June",3:"Catty"};
var number = String(Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.getOwnPropertyNames(name).length)+1);
console.log(name[number]);
```

or so:

```
var name = {"1":"Bob","2":"June","3":"Catty"};
var number = String(Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.getOwnPropertyNames(name).length)+1);
console.log(name[number]);
```

or so:

```
var name = {"1":"Bob","2":"June","3":"Catty"};
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.getOwnPropertyNames(name).length)+1;
console.log(name[number]);
```

Note how first key has no quotation marks and the number variable is equated to a string or to a number, but in all ones the result is ok.

Comment: Object keys are always strings (or symbols now apparently, TIL), even when you assigning or fetching them as numbers.

Comment: Also coercion. The same reason why `("1" - 1) === 0 `